# What C construct could generate this assembly sequence?

Tags: disassembly, x86, static-analysis, c

I have the following disassembly:

```
mov BL, [EAX]
inc EAX
mov [EDX], BL
inc EDX
```

I could see this being the result of:

```
uint8_t foo = bar;
++bar;
uint8_t tmp = foo;
++foo;
```

But this assumes C99. Is there some other C construct that could produce the code above?

Comment: The infamous `strcpy` loop, `*dst++ = *src++` ?

Comment: What's tripping me up is that I had thought that the MOV instruction was limited so that the operands had to have the same size?  This looks like I'm asking "Move a 32b value into the lower 8b of the EBX register."

Comment: `[EDX]` does not stand for "the EDX register". It stands for "the address pointed to by the EDX register". The constrained you mentioned is valid, and in this case the instruction `mov [EDX], BL` is interpreted as "move the lowest byte of the `EBX` register to the byte at the address pointed to by (the value of) the `EDX` register."

Comment: DCoder, would you care to post your comment as an answer so I can give due credit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want the answer without the explanation, scroll to the bottom of this post.

---

The `[register]` notation stands for "*take the value stored in `register` and interpret it as an address*". If the addressed entity size is ambiguous, it can be clarified using `DWORD PTR [register]` for `DWORD`-sized pointers (and similarly for other pointer sizes).

> ```
> mov BL, [EAX]
> ```

This line treats the value in the `EAX` register as a pointer to a single byte (the size of `BL`), reads a byte from that address and stores it in `BL`.

> ```
> inc EAX
> ```

This line increments the value of `EAX`, effectively advancing to the next byte.

> ```
> mov [EDX], BL
> ```

This line treats the value in the `EDX` register as a pointer to a single byte (again, the size of the other operand tells us this), and writes a byte that is stored in `BL` to that address.

> ```
> inc EDX
> ```

This line increments the value of `EDX`, advancing to the next byte.

With all this information, we can see that this sequence basically copies a byte from one address to another. Most likely it is used in a loop such as string copy or memory copy. If there's a line similar to `test BL, BL` afterwards to determine if the copied byte was NULL, it's most likely a string copy; if there's a length/address check instead - it's probably a memory/buffer copy that works on a specified amount of bytes.

---

In C parlance, this can be represented as:

```
char t; // BL
char *src; // EAX
char *dst; // EDX

// initialize src and dst here

t = *src;
++src;
*dst = t;
++dst;
```

Or, as K&R put it ever so tersely:

```
*dst++ = *src++;
```